# Очередь на с++

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define SIZE 100
template <class Qtype> 
class q_type {

Qtype queue[SIZE]; // содержит очередь

int head, tail; // индекс вершины и хвоста очереди

public:
q_type():head(0), tail(0) 
{}

void q(Qtype num); // помещает в объект в очередь

Qtype deq(); // извлекает объект из очереди

void print();

};
// Помещение значения в очередь
template <class Qtype>
void q_type<Qtype>::q(Qtype num)
{
if (tail+1==head || (tail+1==SIZE && !head)) {
cout << "Full" ;
return;
}
tail++;
if (tail==SIZE) tail = 0; // замыкание цикла
queue[tail] = num;
}

// Удаление значения из очереди
template <class Qtype> 
Qtype q_type<Qtype>::deq()
{
if (head == tail) {
cout << "Pusto";
return 0; // очередь пуста или какая-то иная ошибка
}
head++;
if(head==SIZE) head = 0; // замыкание цикла
return queue[head];
}

template <class Qtype> 
void q_type<Qtype>::print()
{   
head++;
cout<<queue[head]<<endl;
if (head==tail) head=0;
}

void main()
{
q_type<char> q2;

int i;
for(i=1; i<10; i++){// dobavka
q2.q(i-1+'A');
}
cout<<"Zapolneno!"<<endl;
cout<<"Output on screen: "<<endl;

for(i=1; i<10; i++){// simple output on screen
    q2.print();
    }
cout<<endl;

cout <<"Izvlechem 1 element "<<i<<" "<< q2.deq() <<endl;

getchar();
}
```

Это похоже на очередь???

Comment: Похоже. Инфа 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать такую очередь:

```
class Queue
{
    int* data;
    int* start;
    int* end;
    int size;
    Queue(int Size): size(Size)
    {
        start=end=data=new int[Size];
    }
    void Add(int Value)
    {
        if(end+1==data+size) {/*Место кончилось или очередь уехала вправо, её надо переместить и\или увеличить память*/}
        *end++=Value;
    }
    int Get()
    {
        return *start++;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Это похоже на очередь.. только жалко, что очередь фиксированного размера (так и задумано?) и, что действительно плохо, так это что очередь не обрабатывает нормально ошибки. А именно, она ничего не делает, если очередь переполнилась.

Comment: Ну, главное что очередь... Мне, в принципе, нужно только различать очередь, стек, дек.... Алгоритм проверки продуман....